# How to test if differences in variation explained (R^2) are significant

Tags: r, multivariate-testing

never posted on here before!

I am using constrained correspondence analysis to test the ability of environmental variables to explain species occupancy data from 30 sites, separately for different treatment groups; I have five treatments in separate plots at each site. The CCA models I am running for each treatment group are identical.

I would then like to test if R^2 values are significantly different among those treatment groups (for example, does environment better explain variation in species occupancy in some groups more than others, such as juveniles vs. adults).

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Rachel. Can you please share some of the code you're currently working with?

Comment: are you using vegan?